# Why Add Multiple Projects to a Single Solution?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

In a lot of tutorials I watch I see the tutors adding multiple projects to single solutions. I was wondering what is the purpose of doing this?

In one ASP.NET MVC 4 example the tutor created a project and added an `Internet Application` to the solution, and then added a `Web API` project to the same solution.

Why are multiple projects added to a single solution in this was? It's a little confusing for me to grasp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an example of [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), but in a scenario where the projects concerned are often/typically/may well be built and deployed as a single entity.

Comment: I wasn't aware of SoC, very interesting. Thanks for that.